# How can i loop over an ArrayList using thymeleaf & spring Boot?

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf and i try to loop over a ArrayList but it doesn't work for me .. some help please:
this is my Html page:

```html
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <table>
            <tr th:each="data: mois">  
                <td class="text-center" th:text="${data}">data</td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is My controller

```html
@RequestMapping(value="/editePlanning", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String editePlanning(Model model){
        Psi psi = psiRepository.findOne((long) 1);
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<psi.getNombreMois();i++){
            int val = psi.getMoisDebut()+i%12;
            data.add(""+ val);
        }

        model.addAttribute("mois",data);
  
        return "editePlanning";
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

You have a typo in your iteration (see [the docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach), they are very good):

```
  <tr th:each="data: ${mois}">
```

Don't forget you can get the [iteration index](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status), useful to generate the id of elements

```
  <tr th:each="data, iterstat: ${mois}">
     <td th:text="${data}" th:id="|td${iterstat.index}|"></td>
  </tr>
```