# How add simple dashboard mensual with spring boot and thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

How add a simple dashboard mensual (Data of some table) with spring boot and thymeleaf any idea or link please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have done?

Comment: thanks for your reply @Krishna,i didn't make anything because i don't have any idea with dashboard how works also i don't  find any link in internet.  any help please

Comment: Check bootstrap components to have an idea of what you could build

Comment: You can check my answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44238020/how-bind-inputs-with-array-using-thymeleaf-and-spring/44241104#44241104 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44047053/how-can-i-loop-over-an-arraylist-using-thymeleaf-spring-boot/44047357#44047357

Comment: thanks @cralfaro for your reply,can i add a template dashboard with bootstrap and spring boot and make my configuration according to my database?